# TalkBack Language Accent

Tags: languages, localization, talk-back, oppo, chinese-language

apologies if this has been asked before, but I've tried looking around on various websites but still unable to find any solution or explanation.

My father is currently using a OnePlus Nord CE 2 5G, he is visually handicapped and has enabled TalkBack on his phone to assist his daily use.

Both is System language and TalkBack language is set to Simplified Chinese, but after several minutes of use, the voice will speak in Chinese but with an American accent? It's quite hard to understand what the voice is saying due to the accent.

Please let me know if there are any fix or solution for this problem, thank you for your time and help!